# SocketChannel write() read() - Non-blocking - Java

Tags: java, sockets

In nonblocking mode, you can register a channel, so when the channel it's ready to write,  to notify the selector.

My question is, how do my channel, know when to write. What are the conditions that the java decides that the channel its ready to write right now? For example does the server (suppose i am a client) notify my channel/socket that its ready to read? so my SelectionKey.OP_WRITE trigger the selector?

I am wondering the same with read(). But i suppose its when the socket already received some data so it notify you to read the already received data. right?

Thanks

Comment: Java doesn't make this decision. The operating system does, specifically the TCP/IP network stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually doesn't tell you when it's ready to physically write, but when it have free space in write buffer or read buffer is not empty to read.